# How to make excel vba code fully qualified / how to circumvent run-time error?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm writing some VBA-code that dynamically sets the properties of some charts, like the data range, upon opening of my excel file. This is because the library I use to export Excel from my .Net project does not fully support chart properties.

I have 4 chart sheets and 1 data sheet in this file.

However, upon the **first opening** of the file, the following error is shown:

```
Run-Time Error: '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Automation
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
```

(also, upon the first opening, a warning is shown that the file is probably insecure and I manually have to allow opening, but I'm not sure if this has any relation to this problem)

Subsequent openings of this file do not trigger the error.

I searched on stackoverflow and in forums and found [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q319832)

Based on the recommendations given there, I tried to make my code fully qualified (for example using the `Dim app As Application` and `Dim wb As Workbook`). However, this didn't solve my problem.

The offending line is marked with **

My questions are:

1. Did I fail to make some part of my code fully qualified?
2. Are there any other possible reasons for this error, and if so, how can they
   be solved?

My code (in the ThisWorkbook object):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim app As Application
Set app = Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = app.ThisWorkbook

Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowString As String
lastRow = wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").UsedRange.Row - 1 + Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Worksheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("A2:G41").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

With wb.Charts("NameOfChart1")
.SetSourceData Source:=wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",D2:E" & lastRow)
'Styling type 1
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 5
'Styling type 2
.SeriesCollection(2).Border.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
.SeriesCollection(2).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
.SeriesCollection(2).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
.SeriesCollection(2).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
.SeriesCollection(2).MarkerSize = 5
End With

With wb.Charts("NameOfChart2")
.SetSourceData Source:=wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",H2:I" & lastRow)
'Styling type 1
.SeriesCollection(1).Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 5
'Styling type 2
.SeriesCollection(2).Border.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
.SeriesCollection(2).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
.SeriesCollection(2).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
.SeriesCollection(2).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
.SeriesCollection(2).MarkerSize = 5
End With

Dim MaxVal As Variant, MinVal As Variant

With wb.Charts("NameOfChart3")
.SetSourceData Source:=wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",F2:F" & lastRow)
MaxVal = app.Max(wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("G2:G" & lastRow))
MinVal = app.Min(wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("G2:G" & lastRow))
If (MinVal = MaxVal) Then
    MinVal = 0
End If
MaxVal = MaxVal + 0.1
MinVal = MinVal - 0.1
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinVal
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxVal
End With

With wb.Charts("NameOfChart4")
**.SetSourceData Source:=wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",B2:B" & lastRow)**
MaxVal = app.Max(wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("C2:C" & lastRow))
MinVal = app.Min(wb.Sheets("NameOfDatasheet").Range("C2:C" & lastRow))
If (MinVal = MaxVal) Then
    MinVal = 0
End If
MaxVal = MaxVal + 0.1
MinVal = MinVal - 0.1
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinVal
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxVal
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 For a nicely explained question :)

Comment: A Shot in the dark. Add `DoEvents` before this line `With wb.Charts("NameOfChart4")`

Comment: `Dim app As Application` isn't fully qualified. This will set `app` to the first object library it comes across in the Tools > References sort order. Better to write `as Excel.Application` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @JimmyPena It looks like the OP is running this code from within Excel application. In this case he doesn't need the Application object at all. He could just use ThisWorkbook or set wb to ThisWorkbook.

Comment: With what you have here, you don't need to worry about the Application (as mentioned by Siddharth; a small advantage of VBA), you need to make sure that you're actually returning something (or they might return Nothing).  Chart4 does exist in the file, along with data in the range?  Also what file formats are we dealing with here (the Workbook and the Data Source)?

Comment: @Mike I would agree except the code actually uses the Application variable. However the code fails after it's used, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Just a small point: To deal with "probably insecure" VBA code it may be a good idea to digitally sign the code. You can test the behaviour by using selfcert.exe before you try to get an official certificate.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I added DoEvents before each With wb.Charts("ChartName"). Also I changed `Dim app As Application` to `Dim app As Excel.Application`. Unfortunately, they didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @ChristophJüngling This code is in an Excel template with some pre-defined Chart-objects. I use NPOI to fill a worksheet in the template with the source data. After that the user can download the result. The VBA code is run upon opening the file. Unfortunately, NPOI itself isn't capable of signing the file (I return the NPOI MemoryStream as a File object from my ASP.NET MVC Controller). Optionally I could add the selfcert.exe in this Controller flow, but I'm afraid it would clutter the Controller flow..

Comment: Moving the fourth `With`-block to the third place does not make the error occur at that block - it always happens at the fourth block, no matter what Chart object / Range is concerned. This rules out the possibility that there is a data-related problem.

Comment: Very interesting. I think the Datasheet object is being lost for some reason.  I've certainly had my share of unexpected quirks in Excel with seemingly good code.  What happens if you split this into two subs, or try to access the DataSheet again after only 3 Charts (and not `With` a chart)?

Comment: Also, with random data on a worksheet and a 4 chart Excel template, I am unable to replicate your error.  I'm using Win7-64 with office 2010.  Also, the script seems to function as expected.

Comment: One more comment: for me the problem does not occur in Excel 2003, Win7-x64, but occurs for me in Excel 2010, Win7-x64

Comment: @wind-rider Try stepping through your code and see what is going on in the locals window. Also you could try referencing to ThisWorkbook instead of using app and wb objects.

Comment: @wind-rider Can you swap the `.SetSourceData` line where the error occurs with a previous one? Maybe there is something wrong with the data in B column. E.g. wrong type of data or something that this chart type doesn't like?

Comment: @Mike given what Wind said about moving the position, I don't think that's the problem.  What happens if you rename the sub "Auto_Open" which is the Excel default to run when opening.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to consider...why aren't you using the built in Worksheets object, it's cleaner than the Sheets collection? Also if the worksheet in Question is not 'first ' it has to have Activate called before you can access fields. (depending on the version of Excel, it may need to be activated in any case so I would recommend doing it regardless) you can do this:

```
wb.Sheets("nameOfWorksheet").Activate
```

Or

```
Worksheets("nameOfWorksheet").Activate
```

Just a note here, you do a lot of repetitive calls into collections. You can't count on the compiler to optimize that for you. Every collection.get(), especially one where a string is resolved to an index number eats cycles. It's better to grab a reference and access the worksheet by that pointer and release it when done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I struggled to find a good solution.
1 of the main issues with my code and getting this (*frustrating*) error was that I had `End` at the end of a code block which was part of a form, which I replaced with `Me.Hide`.

Another thing that helped was to test if the global variables that I declared (as part of a module that represented the application and the workbook) are `Nothing` in code that uses them.

In other words:

```
If app Is Nothing Then
    Set app = Excel.Application
End If
```

And perhaps the same for your wb variable. It might be good to put breakpoints in your code before the use of the workbook and worksheet objects to step through them to see which is the offending line.

Otherwise, check out [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q319832) for some light on the matter.

I hope this helps.

PS. My code was an upgrade from Excel 2003 and it works all the time in the old version without this error.